# Using Maven, TestNG - How to run specific groups in TestNG. Wondering, if what I am doing is even feasible?

Tags: maven, jvm, testng, pom.xml

This is how my POM.xml looks like.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.github.akiraly.reusable-poms</groupId>
        <artifactId>pom-parent-with-spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>MvnTestFramework</groupId>
    <artifactId>MvnTestFrameworkProject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.9.6</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <forkMode>always</forkMode>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <property>
                            <name>reporter.debug</name>
                            <value>false</value>
                        </property>
                    </systemProperties>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                    <reportsDirectory>reports</reportsDirectory>
                    <parallel>methods</parallel> 
                    <threadCount>5</threadCount>
                    <skipTests>false</skipTests>
                    <suitename>${testng.suitename}</suitename>
                    <groups>${testng.groups}</groups>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>utf8</encoding>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>                            
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

This is how my testng.xml looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="testgroups" verbose="1" parallel="tests" group-by-instances="true" preserve-order="false" thread-count="5">
<test name="testgroups" preserve-order="true" group-by-instances="true">
            <groups>
                <run>
                    <include name="group1" />
                    <include name="group2" />
                    <include name="group3" />
                </run>
            </groups>
            <packages>
                <package name="testpackage.*" />
            </packages>
        </test>
    </suite>
```

What I want is: run only specific groups of tests. Meaning, either group1, or group2 or group3, but not all of them to run together at once. 
For the same reason, I have provided {testng.groups} to run the specific group.
In the JVM arguments when I run the testng.xml I specify:
-Dtestng.groups= group2 to run only the group2 tests. However, it just runs all tests in the group1, group2 and group3.

Am I approaching the problem correctly? How can I make sure only a specific set of group runs. Thank you for the help guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try leveraging the Beanshell capabilities that TestNG has to offer, to get this done.

That way, irrespective of how you run your test suite :

- either via your IDE using the TestNG plugin wherein your pom file has no relevance (or)
- via maven wherein maven has relevance

Your suite file's method selector will always be honoured.

In a nutshell, you need to define a method selector that uses Beanshell as shown below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" parallel="false">
    <test name="Test">
        <method-selectors>
            <method-selector>
                <script language="beanshell">
                <![CDATA[whatGroup = System.getProperty("groupToRun");
                groups.containsKey(whatGroup);
                ]]>
                </script>
            </method-selector>
        </method-selectors>
        <classes>
            <class name="organized.chaos.GroupsPlayGround" />
        </classes>
    </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Once you have a suite xml file like this, you can specify the group names via the JVM argument `-DwhatGroup`.

You can also spice up the beanshell script by choosing to run everything if no groups were found via the JVM argument.

For more information you can refer to [my blog post](https://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2013/08/21/beanshell-and-testng/) to get a complete understanding of how to work with the beanshell.

Comment: I was wondering if I could use the same thing for multiple groups? I tried this -DgroupToRun= group1, group2; but this throws an error. I am sure there must be a way to do that.

Comment: In that case, you would first need to parse the value of groupToRun (i.e., split it based on commas), get the split values into a list, iterate that list, and then run the checks. It should be very much doable.